# NuxtJS and Firebase FieldValue Increment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs

I need to use Firebase [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters)s with [nuxt/firebase module](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/).

Here is my code:

```
const increment = this.$fire.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
// some code
snapshot.docs[0].ref.update({ count: increment })
```

That worked well in the regular Vue app, but after migrating to NuxtJS, I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined

It seems like Nuxt Firebase doesn't support FieldValue.

Is there any chance to get it to work?

Comment: How is `this.$fire` initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Same as here:
https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started

`code
  modules: [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
       // config
        },
        services: {
          firestore: true,
        },
]
`

Comment: There's no `$fire` in that snippet or link. Please *edit your question* to show the code of how `this.$fire` is initialized. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there maximize the chances that someone can help you.

Comment: Thank you Frank, just $fire is Nuxt/Firebase utility,  the question was related to NuxtJS firebase module. Maybe the description wasn't clear enough. Please excuse me for that.

With standard initialization code that worked without any problem.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted @Dmitry! 

Answer (score 4):

I had to use $firemodule

This code worked:

```
const increment = this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
snapshot.docs[0].ref.update({ count: increment })
```

https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/usage/#firemodule